# Cannot read property 'id' of null in vuex store module from Localstorage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, vuex, vuex-modules

I have a store module for currentuser. Basically, I retain user data in it after I have logged into my app. However, when I log out, I'm redirected to the login page and remove the current-user data from the localstorage on logging out.

But once I'm logged out, I get this error in my console:

> Cannot read property 'id' of null

This happens because of how I'm initializing values in my currentuser module which is as follows:

```
const currentUser = {
    state: {
        id: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('current-user')).id || '',
        username: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('current-user')).username || '',
    },
```

So it tries to access the localstorage object which no longer exists since I deleted it on log out.
What is the best approach in handling this issue? I'm new with vue so not sure if what I'm doing is a good thing to do even to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
const currentUser = {
        state: {
            id:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('current-user')) && JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('current-user')).id || '',
            username: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('current-user')).username || '',
        }
```

Comment: Okay thanks a bunch! This works! Also, do you think how I'm using a vuex object and initializing it is a good practice?

Comment: Yeah, there is no harm in that. Please upvote and accept my answer if you feel it's right. So that other users can benefit from it too

Answer (score 0):

I think getters would be a better solution, if there's any kind of logic involved (even if it's just checking for existence).

try:

```
const curentUser = {
  getters: {
    id() {
      const cu = localStorage.getItem('current-user');
      if (cu) {
        return JSON.parse(cu).id;
      }
      return '';
    },
    username() {
      const cu = localStorage.getItem('current-user');
      if (cu) {
        return JSON.parse(cu).username;
      }
      return '';
    }
  }
}
```